# stdio.h file not found in cmd

Tags: c++, compilation, turbo-c++

i install turbo c++ in my windows 7 
so when i install in c directory and also i set environment variable like this

```
c:\turboc4\tc\bin
```

and also i set command in turbo blue windows like that options-directories-and set

```
 c:\turboc4\tc\include
c:\turboc4\tc\lib
```

now when i open cmd and enter `tcc C:\TurboC4\TC\BIN\hello.c`
and then i enter `hello.c`
error occur

```
"Unable to open include file 'stdio.h'
```

image file
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vR0i6.png)

IMAGE 2 BULUE SCREEN
[BLUE SCREEN IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F5Pk.png)

any help

Comment: Do people still use turboC++?

Comment: Your compiler is older than me...

Comment: @scorpio By using a good compiler.

Comment: ok now i install codeblock but it shows me error .. check this image http://i.imgur.com/lWhyO4Z.png and also i go settings-compiler- check image http://i.imgur.com/t8gcpUv.png

Comment: Did you install MinGW too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try**

If you have problems like that, first of all your TC folder put in to the C:..drive. after completing installation open turbo c blue screen. there is a OPTIONS > Directories ..in that you can see for option to set up path..

```
include directories..you can set path there now.. C:\TC\INCUDE
libraries Directories..you can set path there...C:\TC\LIB
if you want to store your output in BIN then you can set..C:\TC\BIN..otherwise you can set another path where you want to store your output..
```

Finally you can give OK and finished processes.. It will now work properly

Comment: when i press ATL+O+D pop up windows did not open

Comment: modified answer.. try method 2.

Comment: i think you can read my question properly... i already mentioned i also do that on blue screen

Comment: If you are saving cpp file save it with ".cpp", and for c files save with ".c" . Is that correct?

Comment: please check this : http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/run-c-program-command-prompt-windows/

Comment: did you checked the link above ? First of all go to your file path, then execute tcc filename.c